# How rails do nested form in one form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

The scenario is that, I want to design a `Post` form which is used to record what fruit I eat in one meal, include `picture`, `content`, many kind of `fruit`.
The model relationship is that,

```
Post has_many fruits
Fruit belong_to post
```

I usee `Jquery-ui` to make `autocomplete` in order to help user type their fruit. After they type there fruit tag, it will create a tag under the input field. 
Like this

[image]

However how to I create this in form? I thought about dynamic nested form, but I don't want there're a lots of form, I wish there would be only one input and do the same thing with dynamic nested form.

Here is the [github](https://github.com/fifiteen82726/agriblack/blob/master/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb), please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: Why you need nested form ? I didn't get the question. sorry

Comment: Um...The question is that I want to create a Post and many fruit. But the number of fruit is dynamic.  And I want there is only one input field

Comment: ok.  you can add multiple input fields dynamically. like, when user clicks add more product button

Comment: should I show it in JsFiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click','#add_fruit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  addFruitTag();
});

function addFruitTag(){
  var content = $('#content').val().trim();
  var fruit = $('#fruit').val().trim();
  if(content.length <1 || fruit.length < 1){
    alert("Please fill content and fruit");
  }else{
      $('#fruit_tags').append(
        $('<input>')
        .attr('type','checkbox')
        .attr('name','fruits[]')
        .attr('value',$('#fruit').val())
        .prop('checked','true')
      )
      .append(
        $('<label>')
        .text($('#fruit').val())    
      )
      .append($('<br>'));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="GET">
  Content : <input type="text" id="content" name="content"><br/>
  Fruit : <input type="text" id="fruit">
  <button id="add_fruit">Add Fruit</button><br/>
  <div id="fruit_tags">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Create Post">  
</form>
```

**Note:** I don't have much idea about auto complete plugin, so I have created the function `addFruitTag()`, call it where you are calling your function of adding hash tags of fruits.

And when you will submit the form to the server, you can retrieve the added fruits by accessing the `fruits[]` variable , which will be an array containing the selected fruits tags.

Comment: Thanks, now I know how to figure it out!